# Calling configuration file ID into Linux Command with Date Time from Python

Tags: python, linux, command, subprocess, call

I'm trying to write a script to get the following outputs to a folder (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS = current date and time) using a Linux command in Python, with the ID's in a configutation file

```
1234_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt
12345_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt
12346_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt
```

I have a config file with the list of ID's

```
id1 = 1234
id2 = 12345
id3 = 123456
```

I want to be able to loop through these in python and incorporate them into a linux command.

Currently, my linux commands are hardcoded in python as such

```
import subprocess
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
subprocess.call('autorep -J 1234* -q > /home/test/output/1234.txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call('autorep -J 12345* -q > /home/test/output/12345.txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call('autorep -J 123456* -q > /home/test/output/123456.txt', shell=True)


print now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

The datetime is defined, but doesn't do anything currently, except print it to the console, when I want to incorporate it into the output txt file. However, I want to be able to write a loop to do something like this

```
subprocess.call('autorep -J id1* -q > /home/test/output/123456._now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call('autorep -J id2* -q > /home/test/output/123456._now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call('autorep -J id3* -q > /home/test/output/123456._now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").txt', shell=True)
```

I know that I need to use ConfigParser and currently have been this piece written which simply prints the ID's from the configuration file to the console.

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import os


parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read("/home/test/input/ReportConfig.txt")

def getSystemID():
    for section_name in parser.sections():
        print
        for key, value in parser.items(section_name):
            print '%s = %s' % (key,value)
    print


getSystemID()
```

But as mentioned in the beggining of the post, my goal is to be able to loop through the ID's, and incorporate them into my linux command while adding the datetime format to the end of the file. I'm thinking all I need is some kind of while loop in the above function in order to get the type of output I want. However, I'm not sure how to call the ID's and the datetime into a linux command.

Answer (score 1):

So far you have most of what you need, you are just missing a few things.

First, I think using ConfigParser is overkill for this. But it's simple enough so lets continue with it. Lets change `getSystemID` to a generator returning your IDs instead of printing them out, its just a one line change.

```
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('mycfg.txt')
def getSystemID():
    for section_name in parser.sections():
        for key, value in parser.items(section_name):
            yield key, value
```

With a generator we can use `getSystemID` in a loop directly, now we need to pass this on to the subprocess call.

```
# This is the string of the current time, what we add to the filename
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# Notice we can iterate over ids / idnumbers directly
for name, number in getSystemID():
    print name, number
```

Now we need to build the subprocess call. The bulk of your problem above was knowing how to format strings, the syntax is described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

I'm also going to make two notes on how you use `subprocess.call`. First, pass a list of arguments instead of a long string. This helps python know what arguments to quote so you don't have to worry about it. You can read about it in the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [shlex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#shlex) documentation.

Second, you redirect the output using `>` in the command and (as you noticed) need `shell=True` for this to work. Python can redirect for you, and you should use it.

To pick up where I left off above in the foor loop.

```
for name, number in getSystemID():
    # Make the filename to write to
    outfile = '/home/test/output/{0}_{1}.txt'.format(number, now)

    # open the file for writing
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
        # notice the arguments are in a list
        # stdout=f redirects output to the file f named outfile
        subprocess.call(['autorep', '-J', name + '*', '-q'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks a lot for the input, as that is a huge help. My only concern when I run the code is that python tells me the file does not exist. "No such file or directory "home/test/output/1234_201401106101901.txt." I'm not sure why exactly that is though. From how I'm looking at the code, it appears python should automatically generate the file, which is exactly what I want it to do, but it appears it's not doing that.

Comment: I should also add that the path home/test/output exists, however, the files "1234...timestamp.txt." are not not there, as the goal of this is to have them automatically generated.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a small mistake. You'll notice `open(outfile, 'r')` opens the file for reading which will give us the does not exist error. It should have been opened with `open(outfile, 'w')` for writing. Post is edited

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the datetime using Python's `format` instruction.

For example, you could create a new file with the `1234` prefix and the datime stamp like this:

```
new_file = open("123456.{0}".format(datetime.datetime.now()), 'w+')
```

I am not sure if I understood what your are looking for, but I hope this helps.